# html or latex to pdf parser

Tags: node.js, azure, latex

I am trying to generate receipt and invoice in pdf format

What is the best method:

1. Latex to pdf
2. Html to pdf

I have tried using photomjs to generate html to pdf, but the alignment is difficult. I am thinking about using latex to generate invoice.

Any good latex parser to generate pdf using nodejs hosting on **AZURE**?

Comment: Perhaps [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems currently there is not an application or service on Azure present provides Latex server. And to use latex in node.js, we need to install a TeX distribution like TeX Live or MikTeX.

So you can create an Azure VM and build the application for your requirement.